# def self.foo(arg): rather than def foo(self, arg): in Python

Tags: python

In his [blog post](http://neopythonic.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html) Guido mentions

```
def self.foo(arg):
```

would be acceptable syntactic sugar for

```
def foo(self, arg):
```

I love this.  But was this ever progressed?  Is it ever going to be progressed?
I have had a mighty Google but can't see it as a PEP.

Comment: It hasn't been implemented. It is as it stand syntactic sugar so it is not critical to the build. As to whether it is implemented in future python versions we will not know until it happens or unless user really want it

Answer (score 0):

It was never implemented, and probably won't be. As of Python 2.7 and 3.4, methods are still defined with `def foo(self, arg):`.

The rationale behind this is that it's not a significant enough improvement over the existing syntax to warrant the (frankly non-trivial) effort to implement it, especially considering that it would break all existing code.

Comment: Thanks Max.  Do you know why not?  Or where it was discussed?  I find it one of the biggest mental hurdles to the language, its blemishes particularly obvious because of its otherwise beauty.

Comment: @dave in all honesty it isn't needed. Why fix what isn't broken?

Comment: @PurityLake so newcomers can understand it.  In this sense, I think it's almost a tragedy.

Comment: @dave when I first started learning python, I just accepted it. Most newbies do, they want to code. It's the people who know python want to add more gimmicks to it like `self.foo(args)`. A language needs to focus on build critical goals and not implement new syntaxs unless it is necessary.

Comment: It's not really easier to understand than the existing syntax, IMO. In addition, implementing that would require rewriting *all* OO Python code ever written, which outweighs any possible benefits.

Comment: It wouldn't break any existing code unless they disable the old syntax, which would be silly.

Comment: @MaxNoel I don't think so.  Guido says "can trivially be made backwards compatible"

Comment: Remember that "there should be one (and preferably only one) way to do it" is a core tenet of the Python philosophy (which is what makes the language really easy to learn). So yes, such a change would be a replacement, not an addition. Which is why it wasn't done ;)

Comment: @dave the best way to look at the syntax is that you are passing the class as a parameter so the methods and attributes are exposed to the function. I agree with MaxNoel it makes a lot of sense, especially to newbies. They see self as just another parameter.